# How to open Spring Boot sample in Eclipse STS

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, m2eclipse

I've downloaded Spring boot samples, and I want to run one of them in Spring STS, for instance this one:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

However I have no clue how to import it into Eclipse STS. I tried Import wizard, Import from file system but non of the work ((i get an error that no project exists at the given location).

How can I run this sample in Eclipse STS?

Comment: You can Import as existing maven project

Comment: Cool! Make it an answer so I can accept it if you like!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring boot uses maven as build tool, so you can import the project as existing maven project. The m2e eclipse plugin will then generate the eclipse settings from mavens pom.xml file.

import from file system tries to import an existing eclipse project, but the spring boot demos do not include eclipse settings, as they are independent of the IDE

Comment: @luboskrnac but in the example linked in the question there is a maven pom.xml

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't check the link. Deleted my comment.